# H2 csvwrite: How to substitute a decimal-dot by comma in a decimal(7, 2)-column

Tags: excel, csv, h2

The column-deklaration in the table "PREIS_TAB" is "E_PREIS  decimal(7, 2)".
In the example below H2-CSVWRITE creates in the CSV-Output a dot "." 
in the "Summe E-Preis"-column - it works as designed:

```
call CSVWRITE ('D:\H2-Database\User-Daten\SQL\H2-DB_01/E_PREIS_out.csv', '
               select DATUM          as "Datum"
                    , sum(E_PREIS)   as "Summe E-Preis"
                 from PREIS_TAB
                 group by DATUM 
                 order by DATUM desc
             ', 'charset=UTF-8 fieldSeparator=;');
```

But when I open the CSV-File with Excel (location Germany) the "Summe E-Preis"-column is interpreted not as currency (Excel tries to convert into different date-values) - because of the "." instead of ","s in that column.

I have tried REPLACE, but this works for CHAR-Fields only :-( ... and with some CAST-variations 
no success too.

At stackoverflow-forum here I found following tip but there is still a SQL-mistake - shown as 'N[*]' - or do I need a completely different Syntax:

```
     , cast(format((sum(E_PREIS)) , 'N', 'DE-DE') as varchar(20))
```

How to force H2-CSVWRITE to format the output-column for "E_PREIS" with decimal-**comma**
and not(!) with a decimal-dot?

Comment: This might work as well, but I didn't test it: `select datum as "Datum", replace(preis, '.', ',') as "Summe E-Preis" from (select datum, sum(e_preis) from preis_tab group by datum) order by datum desc`

Answer (score 0):

If you are opening the file manually, you need to go to the `Get External Data` tab on the `Data` ribbon; select `From Text`.  The Text Import Wizard will open and, at Step 3, allow you to specify the format of the values.  And the Advanced tab of Step 3 allows you to specify the Decimal and Thousands separator.

If you are opening this in VBA, this can be automated with the `Workbooks.OpenText` method